# Why is Scala promoting List[Any] to List[Long]?

Tags: scala, primitive-types

In the following code:

```
def test(list: List[Any]): Unit = {
  list.foreach {
    v =>
    v match {
      case r: AnyRef => println(r + ": " + r.getClass.getName)
      case d: Double => println(d + ": Double")
      case f: Float=> println(f + ": Float")
      case b: Byte => println(b + ": Byte")
      case c: Char => println(c + ": Char")
      case s: Short => println(s + ": Short")
      case i: Int => println(i + ": Int")
      case l: Long=> println(l + ": Long")
      case b: Boolean => println(b + ": Boolean")
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + v)
    }
  }
}

test(List(0L, 1.asInstanceOf[Int], 2.asInstanceOf[Short]))
```

here is the output (Scala 2.8.1):

```
0: java.lang.Long
1: java.lang.Long
2: java.lang.Long
```

Why are the numbers being promoted to java.lang.Long? How can I do this so that they either keep their `AnyVal` types or get "boxed" to the equivalent `AnyRef` type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is in [Section 3.5.3 of the language reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

- Byte weakly conforms to Short
- Short weakly conforms to Int
- Char weakly conforms to Int
- Int weakly conforms to Long
- Long weakly conforms to Float
- Float weakly conforms to Double

Because of this, Scala infers that the common type between Short, Int and Long is Long and then converts the non-Long objects to Longs:

```
scala> List(0L, 0, 0: Short) 
res1: List[Long] = List(0, 0, 0)
```

If you want to use the whole chain of weak conformance, try:

```
scala> List(0: Byte, 1: Short, 'c', 3, 4L, 5.0f, 6.0)
res2: List[Double] = List(0.0, 1.0, 99.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
```

And, of course to say that you want a `List[Any]`, just add `[Any]` to your call to `List`:

```
scala> List[Any](0: Byte, 1: Short, 'c', 3, 4L, 5.0f, 6.0)
res11: List[Any] = List(0, 1, c, 3, 4, 5.0, 6.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Type inference works by starting with the most restrictive type (e.g. `Nothing`) and widening until one type can contain everything.  For numeric values, this means widening from `Int` to `Long`.  But now, since the call is effectively to `List[Long](ls: Long*)` all the numeric values are promoted in advance.

So, for instance, all of these give the same list:

```
List(1, 2: Byte, 3: Long)
List(1L, 2, 3: Short)
List(1: Byte, 2: Long, 3: Byte)
```

namely a `List[Long](1L, 2L, 3L)`.  Now, if you don't like this behavior, specify the type of the list as `AnyVal` or `Any`:

```
List[Any](1, 2: Byte, 3: Long)
List.head.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass   // java.lang.Integer
```

---

Edit: P.S. if you are specifying a constant of a certain type, you should just state the type (e.g. `(2: Short)`) instead of casting it to that type (e.g. `2.asInstanceOf[Short]`).

Answer (score 1):

```
List[Any](0L, 1.asInstanceOf[Int], 2.asInstanceOf[Short])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is why (building on the answer by pst):

```
scala> val x = List(0L, 1.asInstanceOf[Int], 2.asInstanceOf[Short])
x: List[Long] = List(0, 1, 2)
```

It seems Scala tries to define the type of the list to be of the biggest object that can contain all the elements. For instance,

```
scala> val x = List(0.asInstanceOf[Short], 1.asInstanceOf[Int], 2.asInstanceOf[Short])
x: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2)
```

So the workaround suggested by pst is the answer.